# Russian stop-motion animation about a love story between a female being made of light, and a male monster that looked something like a satyr

Tags: story-identification, short-film, stop-motion-animation

I was at an Alamo Drafthouse this weekend, and they usually have a fun pre-show with all kinds of strange bits and clips and such. This weekend they had one that really caught my attention, a short film punctuated with commercials and movie trailers, so I missed bits and pieces. Plus they were taking my order at the time.

It was a stop-motion animation fantasy sequence. Some form of love story between a female being made of light, and a male monster that looked something like a satyr. They were in an underground cave and surrounded by garbling monsters, and apparently there was a green twig which would make the monsters blink out of existence. A human man sat and watched the whole thing.

In the end, the night ended, and we see a man and a woman seemingly sleepwalk away from the cave and return to town to climb back into their homes. We follow the man and see it was the man warning the whole story. He wakes up, turns, and picks up a note which I think was translated as a happy birthday note, then the movie ended.

The parts I saw were speechless, playing music and foley effects. I believe it had Cyrillic characters, so I would guess Russian. The end of the credits said 1987 but I couldn't read anything else.

I asked the name of what I was watching and was told "oh, it's just our pre-show. We find and play all kinds of clips of things from YouTube" which didn't help at all. I would like to watch it from start to finish.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know how ID questions should be tagged :-)))

Comment: Was it made with dolls or plasteline? Also how long it was (lower band)?

Comment: May I suggest you look at this [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCo8I0P-E8ELVo3WGo8MV6-Q/videos)? They have a ridiculously rich and surprisingly well-organised collection of Soviet animations, including stop-motion, hand-drawn, full-meter, etc.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  -  do we have a tag for generic animation?

Comment: @Gallifreian [tag:cartoon]?

Comment: @Randal'Thor  -  but it says `short`. What about full-meter animation (e.g. *Coraline*)?

Comment: @Gallifreian Dunno. Not my thing, sorry.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that with a "satyr," it might not be a "love story" in any civilized sense, in case broadening your search helps.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I know but it doesn't allow me to create tags from my cell phone. Wanted to create one for stop-motion and one for animation

Comment: @Broklynite I meant including the [tag:story-identification] tag :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor you are correct, I just automatically assume that story-identification is for written works

Comment: @Gallifreian Thanks for the link to the YouTube channel. I checked it out and went through the list of every single video and I didn't see it. I certainly didn't *watch* all of them, but looking at the thumbnails, none of them looked right, although many certainly had similar style.

Comment: @MissMonicaE I didn't say it was a satyr play.

Comment: What movie was this shown before? I ask because this youtube channel seems to be pretty good about identifying preshow clip sources: https://www.youtube.com/user/coppolascocaine/playlists?sort=dd&view=1&shelf_id=0

Comment: @Paul Secret of NIMH.

Comment: There are other countries that use Cyrillic...Serbia, Ukraine, Bulgaria, Kazakhstan, and Mongolia come to mind.

Answer (score 3):

The only listed stop-motion films from 1987 were:

> 1. 1987   *The Amazing Mr. Bickford* - US (Clay 60min)
> 2. 1987   *My Favourite Time* - USSR (Cel/cutout 80 min)
> 3. 1987   *The Puppetoon Movie*   - (US Puppet    80min)

Assuming that it was *[My Favourite Time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC))*, it can be seen on YouTube:

However there is a [webpage associated with it](http://www.animator.ru/db/?ver=eng&p=show_film&fid=3328) - the email at the bottom might be your best bet on where to obtain a copy of it. Best of luck in your search and let us know if you find it! *sounds really interesting

Comment: I doubt it's "My Favourite Time" - [it's over an hour long (YouTube link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOVsHH711JE), also has a [Wikipedia page in Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Любимое_мое_время_(мультфильм)). I think the OP is referring to a short film.

Comment: Besides, it contains lots of narration, since it's essentially an adaptation of 3 of Pushkin's poems.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn’t look like it, but good thinking! Looks like it was probably a short then.